# How do I Iterate through individual fields of OLD records in Postgres plpgsql trigger?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

Is there a way to iterate through individual fields of OLD records in a Postgres plpgsql trigger?
I want to write a trigger function that logs all the changes that were made to the particular fields of a record. For example:

```
-- My Data Table
CREATE TABLE data (
id integer,
value integer
);

-- My Changelog table
CREATE TABLE changelog (
id integer,
changes text,
user text,
changed_on timestamp
);
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data_history() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    changes text;
BEGIN
    changes := '''';
    IF old.value <> new.value THEN
    changes := CONCAT(changes, old.value, ':', new.value)
    INSERT INTO
            changelog(changes, user, changed_on)
            VALUES(changes, current_user, NOW());
    END IF
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
language plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER change_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON data FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE data_history();
```

While this works as expected the function is completely table-dependent. I would like to make it more generic by comparing all individual fields of OLD and NEW in a loop. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Sure. You can use [`TG_TABLE_NAME`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-DML-TRIGGER-TG-TABLE-NAME) to find the list of column names in `information_schema.columns`. `OLD` and `NEW` records follow the structure of the table the trigger operates on. You put that in a `FOR v_column_name IN select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name=TG_TABLE_NAME LOOP` and use dynamic SQL to inject each column names into your comparison and logging thing.

Comment: http://okbob.blogspot.com/2015/01/most-simply-implementation-of-history.html

Answer (score 2):

Today, the most simple solution can be based on transformation to json type, and then iteration over json:

```
create or replace function trg_func()
returns trigger as $$
declare j json; k varchar; v varchar;
begin
  j := row_to_json(new);
  for k,v in select * from json_each_text(j)
  loop
    raise notice '% %', k, v;
  end loop;
  return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

create table foo(a int, b int, c varchar, d date);

create trigger trg before insert on foo for each row execute function trg_func();

(2023-09-21 19:58:26) postgres=# insert into foo values(10,20,'ahoj', current_date);
NOTICE:  {"a":10,"b":20,"c":"ahoj","d":"2023-09-21"}
NOTICE:  a 10
NOTICE:  b 20
NOTICE:  c ahoj
NOTICE:  d 2023-09-21
INSERT 0 1
```

Iteration over jsonb type will be probably little bit more effective

```
create or replace function trg_func()
returns trigger as $$
declare j jsonb; k varchar;
begin
  j := to_jsonb(new);
  for k in select * from jsonb_object_keys(j)
  loop
    raise notice '% %', k, j[k];
  end loop;
  return new;
end;
```

I did simple performance check.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data_history3()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
  _new jsonb;
  _old jsonb;
  _changes text;
  _k text;
BEGIN
  _new := to_jsonb(NEW);
  _old := to_jsonb(OLD);
  FOR _k IN SELECT * FROM jsonb_object_keys(_new)
  LOOP
    IF _new[_k] IS DISTINCT FROM _old[_k] THEN
      _changes := COALESCE(_changes || ';', '') || format('%s: %s -> %s',
                                     _k, _new[_k], _old[_k]);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  INSERT INTO changelog(tracked_table, changes, "user", changed_on)
    VALUES(TG_TABLE_NAME, _changes, current_user, now());
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

plus

```
create table testdata(a int, b int, c int, d int);
truncate testdata; insert into testdata select 1,1,1,1 from generate_series(1,1000); vacuum analyze testdata;
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER change_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON testdata 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE data_history3();

explain analyze update testdata set a = a + 1, b = b + 1, c = c + 1, d = d + 1;
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                   QUERY PLAN                                                   │
╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│ Update on testdata  (cost=0.00..26.00 rows=0 width=0) (actual time=15.475..15.477 rows=0 loops=1)              │
│   ->  Seq Scan on testdata  (cost=0.00..26.00 rows=1000 width=22) (actual time=0.033..1.478 rows=1000 loops=1) │
│ Planning Time: 0.456 ms                                                                                        │
│ Trigger change_trigger: time=113.583 calls=1000                                                                │
│ Execution Time: 129.378 ms                                                                                     │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
(5 rows)
```

The execution with iteration based on usage of dynamic SQL (@Zegarek)

```
explain analyze update testdata set a = a + 1, b = b + 1, c = c + 1, d = d + 1;
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                   QUERY PLAN                                                   │
╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│ Update on testdata  (cost=0.00..26.00 rows=0 width=0) (actual time=14.168..14.170 rows=0 loops=1)              │
│   ->  Seq Scan on testdata  (cost=0.00..26.00 rows=1000 width=22) (actual time=0.029..1.391 rows=1000 loops=1) │
│ Planning Time: 0.273 ms                                                                                        │
│ Trigger change_trigger: time=687.867 calls=1000                                                                │
│ Execution Time: 702.357 ms                                                                                     │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
(5 rows)
```

The `hstore` type (from extension `hstore`) has very nice functionality for detection difference between two different values
see http://okbob.blogspot.com/2015/01/most-simply-implementation-of-history.html

Comment: That's really very concise, clean and impressive, but it's at the expense of downgrading from native type comparison, two casts down: to comparison of text representations, of json primitve counterparts, of the native types. Not a problem for `text` and `int`, a bit of an issue with date/time, gets more and more problematic from there. This applies to both the `json` and `hstore` approach alike. That being said, I wouldn't be surprised if those were sufficient for 99% of cases, especially since after the comparison, the log saves text anyway.

Comment: @Zegarek - the very effective solution can be done only in C language. Any other is some compromise. Sure there can be problem with comparing, but on second hand the dynamic SQL (`EXECUTE`) is slow, and the query to system catalogue is expensive too. But, anyway, you can run some benchmarks, and the result can be pretty interesting.

Comment: @Zegarek - I run some simple benchmark and jsonb based solution is about 5x faster. There is an dependency on number of columns - on more wide tables the difference will be more significant.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `tracked_table` column to your `changelog` table and set up a generic trigger function you can attach to any table you wish to track.

`OLD` and `NEW` records follow the structure of the table the trigger operates on so you can use [`TG_TABLE_NAME`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-DML-TRIGGER-TG-TABLE-NAME) to find the list of column names in [`information_schema.columns`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-columns.html) then [loop](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING) over them to run your comparisons in a [dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) block. [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/4qI11C5E):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data_history() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    changes text;
    v_column_name text;
    v_diff_found boolean;
    v_old_currval text;
    v_new_currval text;
BEGIN
    FOR v_column_name IN select column_name 
                         from information_schema.columns 
                         where table_name=TG_TABLE_NAME 
    LOOP
        EXECUTE FORMAT(
            $dynamic_sql$
            select $1.%1$I is distinct from $2.%1$I, 
                  quote_literal($1.%1$I), 
                  quote_literal($2.%1$I);
            $dynamic_sql$,
            v_column_name) 
        USING OLD,NEW
        INTO v_diff_found, v_old_currval, v_new_currval;
        IF v_diff_found THEN
            changes := concat_ws(
                           '; ',
                           changes, 
                           v_column_name||':'||v_old_currval||' -> '||v_new_currval
                       );
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    INSERT INTO changelog(tracked_table,changes, "user", changed_on)
    VALUES(TG_TABLE_NAME,changes, current_user, NOW());
    RETURN NEW;
END $BODY$ language plpgsql;
```

Depending on what and how closely you're trying to track, you could consider [pgaudit](https://github.com/pgaudit/pgaudit/blob/master/README.md) extension. If you want to record changes to move back and forth between versions, there's [Continuous Archiving and Point-in-Time Recovery](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/continuous-archiving.html).